# I am trying to tighten harp on lamp. Set screw is stuck

Tags: electrical

I am trying to tighten harp on lamp and set screw is stuck.  I can’t go from bottom of lamp because it connects at the neck and pliers won’t fit up in there

Comment: is there a nut above the saddle flange you can tighten down?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the problem area to your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: you did not ask any questions